# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined when deploying to Play Store using GitHub Actions

Tags: android, github, yaml, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a recent build to Play Store internal testing using GitHub Actions.
The latest version is 3 (1.0.3)
The versionCode and versionName are defined in yml file as follows:

```
  - name: Bump Android version
    uses: chkfung/android-version-actions@v1.1
    with:
      gradlePath: app/build.gradle
      versionCode: ${{ github.run_number }}
      versionName: 1.0.4
```

Error:

```
  Run chkfung/android-version-actions@v1.1
with:
gradlePath: app/build.gradle
versionCode: 6
versionName: 1.0.4
env:
JAVA_HOME_11.0.11_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/11.0.11/x64
JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/11.0.11/x64
JAVA_HOME_11_0_11_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/11.0.11/x64
Gradle Path : app/build.gradle
Version Code : 6
Version Name : 1.0.4
/home/runner/work/_actions/chkfung/android-version-actions/v1.1/index.js:21
        newGradle = newGradle.replace(versionCodeRegexPattern, `$1$***versionCode***`);
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at ReadFileContext.callback (/home/runner/work/_actions/chkfung/android-version-actions /v1.1/index.js:21:35)
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding an extension for the gradle kotlin file, so it should be gradlePath: app/build.gradle.kts